# How do I simplify this $(x^2+y^2)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus

I need some help on how to simplify the following expression. My idea was to use the conjugate of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and multiply top and bottom with it. But I dont know how to continue from there.

$$\frac{x^2+y^2 }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: Answer: $\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$.

Comment: Can you see that $a/\sqrt{a}=\sqrt a$ for any $a>0$?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of my high school years when I saw math as a system of rules and methods provided by the teachers I had. Math get a lot more interesting when it becomes "your math" that you can explore and solve. Here is a list of questions that you can ask to solve the puzzle. What does it mean to simplify between the numerator and denominator and when is it possible? Such simplification occurs when the numerator and denominator have a common factor that is either explicitly there or implicitly there.

Comment: The cool part is when it is implicitly there as you get to make the "hidden" factor "pop out". The next question is whether the factor is in the numerator or the denominator? If you try the numerator, you can ask yourself how can i make the square root in the denominator "pop"/"appear" in the numerator. If you cannot think of anything you can think about what you know about square roots, in particular the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to you problem should be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by applying radical rule.

Comment: This could have been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can think of your fraction as $$\frac{(x^2+y^2)^1}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}},$$
which can then be simplified using the fact that dividing will result in subtraction of the exponents.